# How to reference a variable from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm trying to get a variable `string` and `integer` from

```
Main2Activity.java to MainActivity.java
```

But the problem is that I don't want to use the:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

For it to work. I just want the information to be passed so I can use it in my current activity. Is there any way to do this? What am I missing. This is how my MainActivity looks like:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String A = intent.getStringExtra("Apples");
        textView.setText(A);
    }
});
```

And my Main2Activty:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Apples", "Red");
```

Thanks for helping. Please only comment if you know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an other way, you can define a Class DataHolder and static variable for sharing variable between Activity
Example

```
class DataHolder {
    public static String appleColor = "";
}
```

Then you can use like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
DataHolder.appleColor = "RED";
```

Then

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        textView.setText(DataHolder.appleColor);
    }
});
```